# How can I use the SendMessage behaviour in Unity new input system and pass the InputAction parameter?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a Unity Game (using Unity 2022.2.20).
I want to use the new Input System with the *Send Messages* behaviour. It works fine when I do the OnJump method, but when I try to use the OnMove method (that requires a InputAction parameter) Unity throws a *MissingMethodException*.

I think this is because when using the *Send Messages* behaviour, Unity expects the method to be declared without parameters.

The player is only allowed to move Horizontally, so I configured a 1D Axis on the new input system.
[image]

This is my code:

```cs
public class ControllManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Working as expected
    public void OnJump()
    {
        Debug.Log("Jump");
    }

    // Not working (MissingMethodException)
    public void OnMove(InputAction cc)
    {
        Debug.Log(cc.ReadValue<float>());
    }
}
```

I would remove the InputAction parameter, but I need to know if the player pressed left or right (as a int/float).

Thank you a lot!

I tried to use *InputAction.CallbackContext* as the parameter type, but it keep failing.
I expect to be able to know if the event is triggered as positive (1) or negative(-1). Because triggering the event is possible if I remove the parameter, but I won't be able to know if the user pressed the A for left or D for right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just found the solution:
You need to use the `InputValue` type for the parameter.

```cs
    public void OnMove(InputValue cc)
    {
        Debug.Log(cc.Get<float>());
    }
```